# Magento 2: My shipping method I have created function like convert weight to Grams

Tags: magento2, product, shipping, shipping-methods, product-weight

I have my own website in Magento2 and also use my shipping method I have created below function in Model\Service\AbstractService.php

```
/**
     * Convert weight to kilogram
     *
     * @param $weight
     * @param $weightUnit
     * @param int $roundPrecision
     * @return float
     */
    public function convertWeightToKg($weight, $weightUnit, $roundPrecision = 3)
    {
        return round(
            $this->_carrierHelper->convertMeasureWeight(
                $weight,
                $weightUnit,
                \Zend_Measure_Weight::KILOGRAM
            ),
            $roundPrecision
        );
    }
```

Now I have created new function like Convert weight to grams

so what to do for this function.
give me solution for this.

Comment: what you want? Question is NOT clear.Please explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want created new function like Convert weight to grams above is the example ok

Answer (score 0):

public function convertWeightToKg($weight, $weightUnit, $roundPrecision = 3)

{

switch ($weightUnit) {

```
case 'LBS':
    $finalWeight=$weight*453.592;
    return $finalWeight;
    break;

case 'KILOGRAM':
    $finalWeight=$weight*1000;
    return $finalWeight;
    break;

default:
    return $weight;
```

}
    }

Comment: let me know if any issues

Comment: This is basic structure you can modifiy as per your need

Comment: what is case for gram weight

Comment: default will work

Comment: kindly check this and update if any issues

Comment: @MehulKanjariya kindly check this and let me known